# How to get data key name from data attribute?

Tags: jquery

I want to get key name from my html element?

Sample code :

```
 <td data-code="123">220</td>
```

Using jquery data method I am able to key value but I want to extract key name?

```
var keyValue=$("td").data("code"); //123


var keyName=?????
```

Comment: What are you expecting var `keyName` to return? You mean the '220' ?

Comment: no I want to extract key name as I cannot hard code it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data-code would be the key for that.

If you want to get the keys for unknown key/value pairs you can use a `for (var key in data) {}` loop:

```
var all_values = [],
    data       = $('td').data();
for (var key in data) {
    all_values.push([key, data[key]]);
}
//you can now access the key/value pairs as an array of an array

//if $(td).data() returns: `{code : 123}` then this code would return: [ [code, 123] ]
//you could get the first key with: all_values[0][0] and its corresponding value: all_values[0][1]
```

Comment: Actually I dont know the key name i want to compare with some json data .

Comment: @Nidhi you have to know the key name. this is a dictionary type. key value. you must know the name.

Comment: if i am using $(td).data() // its return {code : 123} , is  any method i am able to get key name from object...

Answer (score 8):

You can access all data keys and values this way:

```
$.each($("td").data(), function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ": " + value); 
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/isijev/edit#javascript,html,live)** is the example.

Comment: This helped me, in my case divs got an arbitrary number of unknown data-* attributes from the backend with some info in them, and I had to loop over them and show each key with their value... Exactly what this does!

Answer (score 1):

I got the element by id and then found it in the attributes map like so

> HTML element

```
<a class="content-link" id="main" data-content="main" href="#"></a>
```

> Javascript

```
$("#main")[0].attributes["data-content"].value;
```

Comment: this should be the top answer. i am not looking to loop through an array, I want the value - thank you for this