# jQuery each loop of all data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, attributes, each

I'm trying to reset data attributes after an animation and am running through some trouble applying the technique from [answer 2 of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459448/how-to-get-data-key-name-from-data-attribute).

Not sure what I'm missing here. Seems theoretically feasible to say for `each` `data` attribute, etc.

---

UPDATE:

Worth mentioning that the `data` keys are all different. E.g. `data-1="abc"`, `data-2="abc"`, etc, hence the need for a `for` loop that simply looks for `data` attributes.

HTML

```
var total = 0;    
$.each($('*').data(), function(key, value) {        
    if (key){    
        var thiis = $(this);            
        total += key;            
        thiis.removeData();            
        thiis.data(total, value);
    }
});
```

Comment: More details needed.! Please post your html.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks for the reply. The HTML in my application changes and is irrelevant to the post - just looking for a theoretical answer on gathering all data attributes within a for loop

Comment: `$('*').data()` is the problem... you need to target a singe element... so change `*` to something else

Comment: are you targeting a particular data attribute or all...

Comment: @ArunPJohny all data attributes. Just edited the post for clarification.

Comment: also there is a difference between the data attribute and the `data()` api... the data api might use the `data-*` attribute to initialize the value after that the changes made using data api will not be reflected in the attribute

Comment: @ArunPJohny noted and applied to my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boom, got it. The script has a lot of overhead, so running it in an instance that a user will wait through isn't an option, IMO. You could improve it with specificity instead of the `*` selector.

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var counter  = 1; // not necessary for your implementation, using it to adjust numeric data keys

$('*').each(function(){ // query all selectors and run through a loop

    var thiis    = $(this),
        dataAttr = thiis.data(),
        i;

    if (dataAttr) { // if the element has data (regardless of attribute)

        var newAttrs = []; // for the element's new data values

        $.each(dataAttr, function(key, value) { // loop through each data object

            var newKey  = key + counter, // calculate new data key
                newAttr = [newKey, value]; // push the new data set

            newAttrs.push(newAttr); // push to elements new attributes array

            thiis
                .removeData(key) // remove the data
                .removeAttr('data-' + key); // remvoe the attribute (unnecessary)
        });

        for (i = 0; i < newAttrs.length; i++) { // for each new attribute

            thiis.data(newAttrs[i][0], newAttrs[i][1]); // add the data
            thiis.attr('data-' + newAttrs[i][0], newAttrs[i][1]); // add the attribute (unnecessary)
        }
    }
});
```